# Notepad++ Sort groups of lines into single line

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with a few thousand lines of the following output.  I'm need each group of six lines to be on the same line with any delimiter between them.

rb=11
rb=24
rb=31
rb=40
rb=44
pb=27

rb=34
rb=36
rb=38
rb=42
rb=50
pb=33

rb=8
rb=12
rb=15
rb=35
rb=50
pb=32

Final output should look like the following.  Thanks.

rb=11 rb=24 rb=31 rb=40 rb=44 pb=27

rb=34 rb=36 rb=38 rb=42 rb=50 pb=33

rb=8 rb=12 rb=15 rb=35 rb=50 pb=32

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

"ctrl + h" to replace in NPP doc.

Find what: (.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)
   (If you have less lines of data or more than the example add or subtract "\r\n(.+)" to get the appropriate amount of lines to merge.).

Replace with: \1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t
   (\1\t represents one field in the new line followed by a tab.)

Answer (score 0):

For a two step method with simple search and replace terms, find a character that is not in the file. Suppose it is the separator character you want, ie `\t`. Do a search and replace of all newlines by the separator: find `\r\n` and replace with `\t`. That produces one very long line where blank lines in the original are now indicated by two adjacent separator characters. Replace all pairs of the separator character with a newline: find `\t\t`and replace with `\r\n`.

If the separator character occurs in the original then three steps are needed. Find a character that is not in the file, suppose it is `!`. Replace all `\r\n` with `!`. Replace all `!!` with `\r\n`. Replace all `!` with `\t` (or the wanted separator character).

Answer (score 0):

Have try with:

Find what: `(rb=\d+)\R`
Replace with: `$1,`